# Layout For Multiple Web Applications on OS X

Tags: javascript, html, macos, cgi

I am wondering what the best way to layout multiple web-development projects on OS X.  Intuitively I think it should be something like this:

- Project1

  - www
  - js
  - cgi-bin
- Project2

  - www
  - js
  - cgi-bin

I would then access it via the web at http://example.com/Project1/www/foo.html and http://example.com/Project2/cgi-bin/bar.py.

However, OS X has the `/Library/WebServer/Documents` and `/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables` as top level entities which is upside-down compared to what I want.  Is there a simple way to accomplish my desired directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

Try SymLinks (see [here](https://gigaom.com/2011/04/27/how-to-create-and-use-symlinks-on-a-mac/)).

Assuming this directory structure for your projects:

```
~/projects/
    project1/
        www/
            js/
            img/
            css/
        cgi/
    project2/
        www/
            js/
            img/
            css/
        cgi/
```

Open a Terminal and go to your `/Library/WebServer/Documents/` folder and type the following to create symlinks to your project folders:

```
ln -s ~/projects/project1/www/ ~project1
ln -s ~/projects/project2/www/ ~project2
```

Then go into your `/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/` folder and type the following:

```
ln -s ~/projects/project1/cgi/ ~project1
ln -s ~/projects/project2/cgi/ ~project2
```

Your `WebServer` folder will now look like this:

```
/Library/WebServer/
    Documents/
        project1/
            js/
            img/
            css/
        project2/
            js/
            img/
            css/
    CGI-Executables/
        project1/
        project2/
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: I think the link target should be `project1` and `project2` instead of `~project1` and `~project2`.  Right?

Comment: I guess that depends on where you put those projects.  If you put them in your home directory, you'll want `~/project1`, but if it's in the root folder, then yes, you'll just want `project1`.